# HTML5 Audio - player load and play only first file from list

Tags: javascript, html, audio, asp.net-core-mvc

I created simple flip card partial view for my petproject:

```html
    <div class="cardBox">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front">
                <h3>@Model.AccentedWord</h3>
                <p>[@Model.Pronunciation]</p>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <h2>@Model.Translation</h2>
                <h3><a asp-controller="Top1kWords" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.WordId">@Model.AccentedWord</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <audio id="player" src="@Model.AudioUrl" type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>
                    <a onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><i class="far fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
                </div><button>Do nauki</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Flip cards are generated correctly, player loaded different audioUrls, but all flip cards play only first loaded sound.

Flip card nr1 has `<audio id="player" src="/sounds/Top1kWords/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>`

Flip card nr2 has `<audio id="player" src="/sounds/Top1kWords/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>`

Flip card nr3 has `<audio id="player" src="/sounds/Top1kWords/3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>`

But all of them play only 1.mp3?

Ho I can make every button play its own sound?

In case of standard player - everything works fine, but I need only "play button" instead of full player.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the `id` that is causing the error. Try using classes and see if that helps.
The code would be:

```html
<div class="cardBox">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <h3>@Model.AccentedWord</h3>
            <p>[@Model.Pronunciation]</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <h2>@Model.Translation</h2>
            <h3><a asp-controller="Top1kWords" asp-action="Details" asp-route-class="@Model.WordId">@Model.AccentedWord</a></h3>
            <div>
                <audio class="player" src="@Model.AudioUrl" type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>
                <a onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><i class="far fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
            </div><button>Do nauki</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I changed  <audio class="player" to  <audio class="@Model.WordId" and now it is uniq!

Answer (score 0):

Thx to @anova01:
I created unique audio id and everything works:
div>